# Windows 7 Wifi keeps connecting to other networks

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, connection

My windows 7 computer is in the wireless network connections and it keeps connecting to other networks well it doesn't connect but these networks keep popping up in my network and I want them to stop popping up because recently my computer has been hacked and I think this is the problem because I never had more than one wireless network connection.

I only have had one and I have read up but haven't found a solution to my problem how do I stop them from trying to connect because some network called Other Network keeps trying to connect and I want it to stop trying to connect. Anyone have any solutions ?

Comment: If your computer is connected through a wireless network, then it is pretty strange that it displays popups to connect to other network (except if your wireless signal is very low and other networks have better signal). If your computer is connected through a wired (Ethernet cable) connection, just disable your wireless card in the device manager...

Comment: your question is a bit confusing.
"other networks popping up in my network"
"connecting to other networks well it doesn't really connect"
and lack of punctuation. Could you be a bit more specific about where they are popping up and what you mean by connecting but not?

Answer (score 2):

If these networks are just popping up where you would usually see your wireless connection, you are safe. Your computer is not being hacked, that is just where your computer displays all the available networks. For you to be hacked, you have to actively try to connect to one of these unknown networks, and even then, it is unlikely. More likely you have been hacked through the internet, not your own network.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are seeing something like this:

[image]

These are just a list of networks in the area that your computer can connect to. That said, I'd recommend you use a good antivirus software, such as Malwarebytes to keep your computer safe from harm.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I really have to start remembering to add images on these sites instead of links ^_^